# What to do when Ubuntu support ends? How do you port your data to a newer version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, support

I want to install Kubuntu on my laptop instead of Ubuntu, but the problem is its support ends soon and I'm new to this environment, so I don't know what to do when the support ends.

Do we get an update or do we need to clean install the newer version?

Comment: That is up to you to decide. I arranged my system such that / and /home do not contain content so I re-install every 6 months and re-attach my data partition. Feel free to do in differently :)

Comment: If you're talking about 14.04 the support already ended. Regardless of the flavor please install a supported release. Any LTS release is supported for 5 years (all the others have 9 months only). The newest LTS - 18.04 -  has support until 2023. And yes, and release can be upgraded on-line.

Comment: If you want to install Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu, do it, but go with a supported release. You don't have to port anything. I'd install Kubuntu 18.04 and upgrade when the new LTS is released in April 2020.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about 14.04 the support already ended. Regardless of the flavor please install a supported release. Any LTS release is supported for 5 years (all the others have 9 months only). The newest LTS - 18.04 -  has support until 2023.

And yes, any release can be upgraded on-line.

Comment: The support for some flavours is less than 5 years. Kubuntu 16.04 is also EOL now.